# TextView.setText() does not update the text

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I have a `TextView` inside a `fragment` named `monthYearName` . and i have added that fragment inside a view pager twice.I try to set its text with this function :

(next is an ImageView )

```
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    monthYearName.setText("SomeText");

        }
    });
```

but the `TextView` does not get Updated and show the provided text.
please note that THE TEXT IS NOT null or empty , the onClick callBack calls on right time and when I use this line :

```
          Log.d(monthYearName.getText().toString)
```

it returns what ever I set in the text view. it just dont show them on the screen.
I have used

```
          getView().Invalidate();
```

also

```
          monthYearName.Invalidate();
```

but none of them worked!
also note that the fragment doesn't contains more codes. just findViewById's and above codes.
thanks.

Comment: Do you even read this question?? how people give -1 when they even cant answer my question?????????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will give you a hint maybe this will help, 
make sure if you use `viewpage` that you don't have a `multiple fragments` with the same `id` for the `textview` that can make conflict so everything seemed fine,with no error message, but the text simply didn't change.

Comment: Thanks! i actually used a view pager, but i added same fragments twice. so that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
String str=PersianCalendarHandler.monthsNamesOfCalendar(date.getMonth()) + "  " + date.getYear();
monthYearName.setText(str);
```

Comment: as i said ,the string is ok. and when i getText the string, it returns the current date and time in logcat. but it doesnt show them on the mobile screen in textView

Comment: show your full code

Comment: its almost all the code. skipping findViewById's

Comment: there is any other method after text chnaged like

Comment: no ,just this method.

Comment: can you post full code?